Salesforce Validation Rule - make a picklist field required when checkbox is true
This seems like it should be simple, but I'm struggling.
I have two fields:
ApprovedSupplier__c is a checkbox, when it's checked and it's value is true, I need the picklist field SupplierTier__c to become a required field - or just be able to display an error message saying that the Supplier Tier must now be completed.
Can anyone help me write this formula?

What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're running into an error trying to save a validation rule, you should copy/paste it here (in full, don't try to shorten or paraphrase it). You can [edit] your question to add that information.

One simple way is to use the validation rule, and try it on the object these fields are:
ApprovedSupplier__c = true
&&
NOT(ISPICKVAL(SupplierTier__c,"")) 


Note that <boolean field> == true can always be reduced to just <boolean field>. Likewise, <boolean field> == false reduces to NOT(<boolean field>) or !<boolean field> (they're both equivalent, just a matter of preference).

Thank you for your help!

The validation rule formula you can use is as below:
AND(
   ApprovedSupplier__c,
   ISBLANK(TEXT(SupplierTier__c))
)

What this rule does:

The AND function checks that both conditions within it are true.
ApprovedSupplier__c checks if the checkbox is true (checked).
ISBLANK(TEXT(SupplierTier__c)) checks if the SupplierTier__c picklist field is blank.


Perfect, thank you!
